# JavaScript - user selection function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I am new to JavaScript and I'm working on something. [This](http://web.csulb.edu/%7Emmessiha/cecs110/MyStuff/) is what I've reached so far and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Editor V 1.0</title>
<script>
function changeOpacity(newValue) {
    document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = newValue*100 +'%';
    document.getElementById("image1").style.opacity = newValue;
}

var color = true; 

function imgColor() {
     if (color) {
       document.getElementById("image1").style.WebkitFilter = "grayscale(100%)";
       color = false;
     } else {
       document.getElementById("image1").style.WebkitFilter = "none";
       color = true;
     }
 }

function colorImg() {
    document.getElementById("image1").style.WebkitFilter = "none";
}

function greyImg() {
    document.getElementById("image1").style.WebkitFilter = "grayscale(100%)";
}

function userImage() {
    var link = document.getElementById("userImg").value;
    document.getElementById("image1").src = link;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="colorImg()">Colored</button>  
<button onclick="greyImg()">Greyscale</button>
<button onclick="imgColor()" >Alternate</button><br><br>

Opacity :<input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.2" onchange="changeOpacity(this.value)"/> 
<span id="span">100%</span> <br><br>

Try your own image! <input id="userImg" type="text" placeholder="Enter url here">
<button onclick="userImage()">Go!</button>
<br><br>

<img class="myImages" id="image1" src="image4.jpg">
<img class="myImages" id="image2" src="image2.jpg"> 
<img class="myImages" id="image3" src="image3.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

So far, the "Colored", "Greyscale", and "Alternate" buttons along with the opacity slider work as intended only on the first image (image1.jpg). Also, when the user inputs his own image, it replaces the first image and the functions work on it as intended. **Here is what am trying to do:**

1 - Let the user select which of the three images he wants to edit by clicking on it, then apply a border around it and use it in the other functions (greyscale and opacity). Here's what I tried (but didn't work):

```
<img class="myImages" id="image1" src="image4.jpg" onclick="selectImg(this.id)">
<img class="myImages" id="image2" src="image2.jpg" onclick="selectImg(this.id)"> 
<img class="myImages" id="image3" src="image3.jpg" onclick="selectImg(this.id)">

function selectImg(imgID) {
  document.getElementById("imgID").style.border = 50px;
}
```

2 - When the user inputs his own image, I want it to replace all the 3 images I have displayed by default.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes both on the id and the `50px`. But it is better to define a style for the selection.

Then let a click handler first remove that style from all the images, except the clicked image, where it should set that style. The functions `.classList.add` and `.classList.remove` can be used for that.

Where you currently have `document.getElementById('image1')`, you would do instead:

```
document.querySelector('.selected')
```

Then you should also make sure that the page loads with one image selected, i.e. with the `selected` class.

Some other improvements make sure that when changing the selection, the opacity slider is also brought in line with that image's current opacity setting.

Here is a snippet that does all that:

```js
function changeOpacity(newValue) {
    document.getElementById("span").textContent = newValue*100 +'%';
    document.querySelector(".selected").style.opacity = newValue;
    document.querySelector('input[type=range]').value = newValue;
}

function getOpacity() {
    return parseFloat(document.querySelector(".selected").style.opacity || '1');
}

function isColor() {
    return document.querySelector(".selected").style.WebkitFilter !== "grayscale(100%)";
}

function imgColor() {
    document.querySelector(".selected").style.filter =
    document.querySelector(".selected").style.WebkitFilter = 
         isColor() ? "grayscale(100%)" : "none";
}

function colorImg() {
    if (!isColor()) imgColor()
}

function greyImg() {
    if (isColor()) imgColor()
}

function userImage() {
    document.querySelector(".selected").src = document.getElementById("userImg").value;
}

// Add this function, and call it on click on an image
function select(img) {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.myImages')).forEach( 
        myImg => myImg === img ? myImg.classList.add('selected')
                               : myImg.classList.remove('selected')
    );
    // bring opacity slider in line with selected image
    changeOpacity(getOpacity());
}
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="colorImg()">Colored</button>  
<button onclick="greyImg()">Greyscale</button>
<button onclick="imgColor()">Alternate</button><br><br>

Opacity :<input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.2" onchange="changeOpacity(this.value)"/> 
<span id="span">100%</span> <br><br>

Try your own image! <input id="userImg" type="text" placeholder="Enter url here">
<button onclick="userImage()">Go!</button>
<br><br>

<img class="myImages selected" id="image1" onclick="select(this)"
    src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-icon.png?v=93426798a1d4">
<img class="myImages" id="image2" onclick="select(this)"
   src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"> 
<img class="myImages" id="image3" onclick="select(this)" 
   src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.png?v=6c3100d858bb">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works exactly the way I wanted, except for the coloring functions. Am sure it's a tiny mistake I just can't figure it out as am completely new to this.

Comment: I had indeed an error regarding the color/grayscale. It should be fixed now. I also added a line assigning this setting to the `filter` style attribute, so that it also works in FireFox.

Comment: So I added some stuff here and there and that's what I have now [(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/bhvcr035/) and here is the page [link](http://web.csulb.edu/~mmessiha/cecs110/MyStuff/). The first time I select one of the images, the border shows up. But after I click my reset button and try to select an image again, the image gets selected but without the border showing up.

Comment: If you have a new question, please create one for it. These comment sections are not suitable (nor intended) for follow-up questions. If you post a new question, let me know, and I will be happy to look at it. Just take care to look at the console for errors. In the jsfiddle there are errors about `changeOpacity` and `select` not being defined (as functions).

Answer (score 0):

First - you are not using that imgID, but String like that variable. Change to:

```
function selectImg(imgID) {
  document.getElementById(imgID).style.border = 50px; //notice no quotes for imgID
  activeImage = imgID; //set activeImage ID
}
```

And then when you are doing something to an image, don't use "image1", but `activeImage` that is global variable (defined outside and before functions).

And **as for new uploaded image**: 
Put it into another div and work with such algorithm -

```
when (uploaded_new)
   hide default pics
   show DIV with new image
   activeImage = uploadedPic
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't quite get what you mean by "activeImage". I go with image1, image2, image3 so I can name all the 3 images I have. If you can explain a little bit more I would really appreciate it, thanks again!

Comment: activeImage is just a variable, where you store the id of chosen image. i.e. when you click on second, activeImage will be "image2". and when you call those editing functions, instead of static "image1" you use variable, that stores needed value (id of last chosen picture).